# Компилятор выкидывает ошибку при попытке ввести тест программы полностью(скопировать).Если вводить построчно, то все работает C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Num1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0;
            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            string[] sum =Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            int[] num = new int[n];
            int flag = 1;
            for(int i = 0; i < sum.Length; i++)
            {
                num[i]=Convert.ToInt32(sum[i]);
            }
            int ot = 0;
            int it = n - 1;
            if (n != 1)
            {
                while (ot != it)
                {
                    if (flag == 1)
                    {
                        if (num[it] > num[ot])
                        {
                            sum1 += num[it];
                            it--;
                        }
                        else if (num[ot] > num[it])
                        {
                            sum1 += num[ot];
                            ot++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            sum1 += num[ot];
                            ot++;
                        }
                        flag = 0;
                    }
                    else if (flag == 0)
                    {
                        if (num[it] > num[ot])
                        {
                            sum2 += num[it];
                            it--;
                        }
                        else if (num[ot] > num[it])
                        {
                            sum2 += num[ot];
                            ot++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            sum2 += num[ot];
                            ot++;
                        }
                        flag = 1;
                    }
                }
                if (flag == 1)
                {
                    sum1 += num[ot];
                }
                else
                {
                    sum2 += num[ot];
                }

                Console.Write("{0}:{1}", sum1, sum2);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("{0}:{1}", num[0], 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

тест:
4

5 25 1 5

ошибка:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.Convert.ToInt32(String value)
   at Num1.Program.Main(String[] args) in
```

Comment: Возьмите отдадите (запустите по. F5) и посмотрите, на какой точно строчке падает и какое значение стоки оно притом пытается в into преобразовать.  Скорее всего проблема в том, откуда копируете - например,  там в кавычках может быть неразрывный пробел вместо обычного, и вашу строчку из-за этого не разрезает

Comment: Я понял в чем проблема, но пока не могу исправить. Я разбиваю строку на отдельные цифры через Split, если после последнего числа поставить пробел, то система выкидывает неверный формат строки. Осталось только продумать, как убрать пробел после 5

Comment: `.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Comment: Да, спасибо большое, еще это можно поправить, если крутить цикл не до s.Length, а до n, т.к Length ест некорректно